# Creaking sounds from the saddle tube?

Tags: frames, creak

I've started to hear creaking/clicking sounds from the saddle tube. **Is the frame giving up?**
I could look for [a longer saddle post](http://www.amazon.de/XXL-ALU-SATTELST%C3%9CTZE-%C3%9CBERL%C3%84NGE-50/dp/B003IB77WC/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1405670710&sr=8-9&keywords=fahrrad%20sattelstange), if that would relieve some of the strain on this part of the frame, but I'm not sure what length to get.

I've measured the outer diameter of the post to be approx. 27mm -- but what is the proper name/size for this dimension?

It's a 58 (cm/in?) aluminum frame with 28" wheels, roughly 10 years old. I've got the saddle fairly high, but I'm a tall guy (192cm, 95kg) so it needs to be like this. When I put a heel on the lowest pedal, my leg is practically straight. Perhaps I should buy a bike with a bigger frame, if that exists, but I am hoping to avoid significant expenses. The bike is otherwise in good condition.

**Updates to comments:**

- Saddle post is 1cm lower than its "max" mark. Close, but okay - perhaps too close, given my weight? (95kg)
- frame and post is metal, presumably both aluminum.
- Creaking goes away when standing. That's why I suspect this area.
- Saddle clamp and rails seem good on visual inspection.

[image]

Comment: Did you respect the max marking on the saddle post? If that shows outside the seat tube, this could damage both the frame and the post. Otherwise, remove the post, grease lightly, reinstall. This could help, too.

Comment: Thanks, I checked for such a mark but didn't find any.

Comment: Every saddle post should have this mark. It's about a third from the bottom iirc. Maybe it was printed on an the print is now gone, but it should have had such a mark.

Comment: Of course you're right :) I just removed the saddle post and found the mark 1cm below the point that meets the tube, so technically it's not too high but I might still be putting too much weight on it. I also greased it while it was out; let's see if that helps! Put it as an answer?

Comment: Let's see if it helps first.

Comment: What is the material of the frame?  (I'm guessing aluminum.)

Comment: Yes @DanielRHicks it's aluminum.

Comment: And the post is also Al?

Comment: I can't tell, @DanielRHicks. (It is written on the frame, that's the only way I knew that.)

Comment: It's not a carbon fiber post?  Then almost certainly aluminum.

Comment: It's definitely metal! There's no space-age technology on this horse :) Yeah, black-anodized aluminum would fit the bill.

Comment: The problem with diagnosing these things is that bicycles are made of hollow tubes so its pretty easy for a sound in one portion to transmit to sound like its coming from another portion. As for weight, a 58 should fit a decent number of people, so maybe try a lighter friend and see if they have no noise?

Comment: Go through and torque to spec.  If you are standing (not on seat) and pedal hard does the creak go away?

Comment: Remove the post, grease lightly (perhaps use an "anti-seize compound") and reinstall.  Torque the fixing bolt to spec.

Comment: If greasing and reinstalling seatpost doesn't help you might try replacing the seatpost. Sometimes seatposts make creaking noises before they break. Also check that the saddle clamp is properly tightened and that saddle-to-rail connections aren't failing.

Comment: And, given that it's an aluminum frame, check carefully around the clamp and the adjacent welds for any cracks in the frame.

Answer (score 4):

Often, dirt gets between the seat post and seat tube. Remove the seat post. Clean the post. Clean inside the seat tube. Grease the post and re-install. Hopefully the noise will be gone. You say the post is close to the max mark. For a little added safety, longer seat posts are available.

Comment: Dirt also introduces corrosion much faster and I find that "creaking" often comes from rusty surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably, the seatpost just needs to be cleaned (dust gets in) AND/OR tightened a little bit. Don't overdo it, it's best to stay within the 5-6 Nm range so as not to bust your seatpost ring or seat tube. Greasing the seatpost might also help. I wouldn't recommend any actual grease for this (messy, tends to get the seatpost stuck after a year of riding), powdered graphite is more appropriate.

Comment: You sure about the 50 Nm? On the seat post clamp on one of my bikes, the following is written: 5-6 Nm.  Fairly light torque!

Comment: Tightening to 50 Nm has the potential to strip the seatpost clamp and/or crack the seatpost (if carbon)...I hope you mean 5-6 Nm, correct?

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow tall guy, try temporarily lowering your seat by half and see if the creaking goes away.  If yes, your seatpost is simply too high and unsupported, so buy a longer one.  350mm and 400mm are available now, not overly expensive.

Have a good close look at the frame for cracks too - I broke a frame by having the seat too high.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put tube lower enough and check how it sounds in that position. If any sounds don't appear then just replace with new longer tube. It saves your frame. 
Or it might be sand or dirt cause noise. So try to clean up tube and frame.